# CakePHP Media Plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to configure Media Plugin ( https://github.com/davidpersson/media )

in the core.php

```
    require APP . 'plugins/media/config/core.php';

$xsmall = array('fitCrop' => array(75, 50));
$small = array('fitCrop' => array(75, 50));
$medium = array('fitCrop' => array(220, 140));
$large = array('fitCrop' => array(700, 335));
$xlarge = array('fitCrop' => array(700, 335));

Configure::write('Media.filter', array(
    'audio' => array(),
    'document' => array(),
    'generic' => array(),
    'image' => compact('small', 'medium', 'large'),
    'video' => compact('medium', 'large')
));
```

from command line i have created the initial Directories

In my User's Model i have added this

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $actsAs = array('Containable', 'Media.Transfer', 'Media.Generator', 'Media.Coupler');
```

Upload form

```
        <!-- Display Photo Form -->
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array( 'controller' => 'users','action' => 'display_photo', 'type' => 'file')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->file('display_photo'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Upload', 'id' => 'upload-button', 'name' => 'upload-button', 'div' => false)); ?>
        <!-- Form Ends -->
```

Action display_photo

```
function display_photo(){
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        debug($this->data);
        $this->User->save($this->data, array('fields' => array('display_photo')));

    }
}
```

Error

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' 
[CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

Comment: do a debug on `display_photo`. I expect it will be a multidimensional array. `fields` expects `array('field_one', 'field_two')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if the media plugin is capable of saving filenames and directory in one field (from ur ex its: display_photo) but I do sure that if you added fields `basename` and `dirname` (remove display_photo), I think that should work.

Also you need changed your display fields to echo $this->Form->file('file');

Comment: yeah thanks.. once i changed display_photo to file it worked.. basename and direname are optional i think